# Pandas: Separate a character column into multiple columns with a regular expression

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

I am trying to translate a dplyr pipeline to pandas:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    separate(col1, c("col3","col4"), extra = "merge") %>%
      separate(col2, c("col5","col6"),
               sep = "[[:space:]]",
               extra = "merge") %>%
      .....
```

This pipe basically split the following data set:

[image]

```
col1            col2            col3    col4     col5        col6
XXXXX 5555 SP   TEST-GEN ABC    XXXX    5555 SP  TEST-GEN    ABC
```

When trying to split the column I want as:

```
import pandas as pd
df = df.col1.str.split(n=1)
```

I get a pandas.core.series.Series object with the following shape:

```
0                               [XXXXXX, 5555 SP]
```

I can access the elements with:

```
df[0][0]
```

But I would like to know if there is a better manner of try to do what I was doing with dplyr.

BR
/E

Comment: You can for example assign straight to two columns using `expand=True` in your `split`: `df[["col3", "col4"]] = df["col1"].str.split(n=1, expand=True)`

Comment: I believe that’s an answer, not a comment, @tomjn :)

Answer (score -1):

This should be what you want:

```py
>>> from datar.all import c, f, tribble, separate
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.col1,           f.col2,         
...     "XXXXX 5555 SP",  "TEST-GEN ABC", 
... )
>>> 
>>> df >> separate(
...     f.col1, c("col3", "col4"), extra="merge", remove=False
... ) >> separate(
...     f.col2, c("col5", "col6"), sep=r'\s+', extra="merge", remove=False
... )
            col1          col2     col3     col4      col5     col6
        <object>      <object> <object> <object>  <object> <object>
0  XXXXX 5555 SP  TEST-GEN ABC    XXXXX  5555 SP  TEST-GEN      ABC
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.